# CREACIÓN Y GRABACIÓN DE FICHERO EXCEL CON JUPYTER NOTEBOOK

Tags: python-3.x, excel, jupyter

estoy introduciéndome en la creación de hojas de excel con jupyter notebook, mi código, que no es exactamente mío, es el siguiente:

```
 #Importamos el módulo xlwt previamente descargado y creamos función main
 import xlwt
 def main():
 #Creamos una instancia de xlwt.Workbook y añadimos una hoja de nombre PySheet1
     book=xlwt.Workbook()
     sheet1=book.add\_sheet('PySheet1')
 #Definimos el contenido a insertar
     cols=['A','B','C','D','E']
     text='Row\%s,Col\%s'
 #Hacemos un bucle de 5 iteraciones con 5 filas y columnas con contenido
     for num in range(5):
         row=sheet1.row(num)
         for index,col in enumerate(cols):
             value=txt\%(num+1,col)
             row.write(index,value)
     book.save('test.xls')
 if __name__ =='__main__':
     main()
```

El error que me da es el siguiente.
File "", line 6
sheet1=book.add_sheet('PySheet1')
^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

No entiendo muy bien ese error, si alguien me puede echar una mano se lo agradecería

Comment: `add\_sheet` ¿Qué hace esa barra `/` ahí?. Por cierto recomiendo que uses pandas

Comment: Pandas lo utilizaré más adelante, es un código que me han pasado ya que estoy aprendiendo  python y la realización de hojas de excel con python, está puesto tal cual y me da error. Por otra parte, el último bucle y el condicional no los entiendo

Comment: Pues quita esa barra invertida y seguro desaparece el error. También deberías investigar sobre el módulo que usas. Nunca es bueno copiar y pegar código sin entenderlo

Comment: Lo estoy haciendo correr por líneas y ahora me da 'PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: nombre del fichero creado', y sólo he puesto las 4 primeras líneas de creación de la instancia y la hoja de excel

Comment: Eso se debe a que tu script no tiene permisos, deberías otorgraselos, la forma de hacerlo varía según el S.O. que uses